# Trouble installaling lxml on python 3.6.1

Tags: python, installation, lxml

I am getting the error python version 3.4 required which is not there on registry when i try to install lxml3.6.1 on my python version 3.6.1
any help on resolution is greatly appreciated

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Don't put answers in questions. Either write an answer below or, as the thing you did to solve is literally the first thing you should have tried, delete the question.